# Office Icons in Windows 10 "Open File" Dialog

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, office365

Platform: Windows 10 Pro, Office 365

In the "Open file" dialog of any Office program appears an additional icon on top level for the currently open office program. However, with whatever files I work actually, the right pane shows nothing.

[image: Office Icon in Windows Explorer]

In the example shown I have PowerPoint open (and already a presentation loaded). I'm going to open another presentation getting the open file dialog with the view shown in the picture.

Same in Word:

[image]

It's consistent and it has always current icon. Each office app shows just itself, even if others are open.

The icon has, though, no visible features I could use.

So, I'm asking, what's the purpose?